# What terminal command checks the Ubuntu version

Tags: command-line, versions

What terminal command tells the version of Ubuntu.

Comment: @fossfreedom this question is not a duplicate of the question you linked because i am asking how to check using terminal, not the graphical way. remove your concern

Comment: The duplicate covers both terminal and graphical. IMHO they are the same question.  These probably should be merged.  I'll ask some 20K users before making that decision.

Comment: the duplicate does but the question doesnt. when others search for a terminal command and they find the other question, they wount look into it because it doesnt say anything about it in the question description

Answer (score 140, accepted):

For the description and the release number including the OS name, run:

```
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
```

Just for the the codename, use:

```
$ lsb_release -c
Codebase:   precise
```

For the release number only, use:

```
$ lsb_release -r
Release:    12.04
```

For all [lsb](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/lsb) version details, use:

```
$ lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

Comment: That gives the codename. for the description including the OS name ("Ubuntu" on an Ubuntu system) and the release number, use `lsb_release -d`. For the release number only, use `lsb_release -r`. For all available `lsb` information, use `lsb_release -a`.

Comment: Note on 16.04 there it does not work. Getting message instead "No LSB modules are available."

Answer (score 79):

This should give you what you want:

```
cat /etc/lsb-release
```

Comment: Using `lsb_release`just gives me "No LSB modules are available". This does the trick.

Comment: Use lsb_release -ra

Comment: Works on 16.04 unlike `lsb_release`.

Comment: Fiddling around with Ubuntu via Docker, and this command works if you're using the 16.04 version and later and 12.04. The one in the accepted answer works for the 14.04 release.